# How to relate Her and Active Record models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an API for asset management, and I'm building a Rails app that is the client for the API using [Her](http://github.com/remiprev/her), but also handles authentication.

I have a User Active Record model. How can I relate the Her model and the Active Record model?

The code is this:

```
class Resource
   include Her::Model
   has_many :bookings
   parse_root_in_json true, format: :active_model_serializers
end

class Booking
   include Her::Model
   belongs_to :User
   belongs_to :Resource
   parse_root_in_json true, format: :active_model_serializers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :Bookings
end
```

Currently if I try to get the user for a booking, I'm getting the id field stored in the booking object, not the user object as I need.

```
irb(main):067:0* Resource.find(1).bookings.where(status:  'all').first.user
=> "1"
```

Comment: For other readers, who have no idea what `her` is: 'Her' is a replacement for the old and ancient `ActiveResource`. Link: https://github.com/remiprev/her I had never heard of it before, seems like a great gem. It would help to explain this a bit more in the question, I guess that caused the downvote? Is the uppercase `User` and `Resource` in the `belongs_to` intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have the possibility, but instead of having a `user` field in returned from your `Booking` API call, call it `user_id` and then you could have something like:

```
def user
  @user ||= User.find(self.user_id)
end
```

If you cannot change the API, you could do almost the same, but the naming would get a bit weird.
I use the `||=` to make sure you only look up a specific user once for a given `booking`.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked! just got to convert to int to make it work (self.user_id.to_i)